# Earth Grounded 12V DC System

Tags: reverse-engineering

I'm very confused about this design i've come across in the field. A data acquisition system is powered by a 12V ACDC power brick. But then inside of the chassis is a DC-DC converter, also isolated, where the output GND is tied to the chassis, and to earth...

Why? There are no high voltage systems here, so I can't imagine this can be for safety. Can earth grounding the common GND of a digital system prevent noise? Is it wise to do this?

Another question I have is whether grounding the output of an isolated converter breaks the isolation of that converter.. In other words, is the output of the converter no longer floating since it's now tied to earth?
[image]

Comment: Just curious - how is the connection to earth made, if not via the power brick cable? Is there a separate, dedicated wire from chassis to earth?

Comment: That would be called a Class I device.

Comment: @SimonFitch The earth ground actually comes from the AC-DC brick. Unlike barrel jacks, 5 and 8 pin DC connectors usually have earth ground.

Answer (score 1):

If you're designing a piece of equipment with a metal chassis, unless there are other considerations at play it's a good idea tie your circuit ground to chassis ground in at least one spot.  This assumes that the system you're working with was done wisely, that the designer assessed how the data acquisition system would work, and that they determined that grounding the boards to the chassis was the right thing to do.

For low-production equipment of a certain era, those DC-DC converters were often the cheapest way to get the voltage you wanted, even if you didn't want an isolated converter.  That's probably why that converter was chosen.

Comment: Why use an isolated converter on the inside of the chassis, then only earth ground the output side? If a wire came loose on the input side, would the protection still work?

Comment: @BobaJFET Yes, because it's isolated. The equipment would just stop working.

Comment: @Finbarr That might be true but what if the metal chassis makes contact with both ends of the input side of the DC - DC converter? I don't have it shown in the diagram but there is a + and GND going into that converter.

Comment: @BobaJFET Then it'll short out the power brick, regardless of whether the converter is isolated or the chassis is grounded.